# ASP.NET MVC 3 URL Routing problem with Custom Route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing

I have the following Custom URL Routing Rule:

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
          "RaceRoute", // Route name
          "people/create/{raceid}/{id}", // URL with parameters
          new { controller = "People", action = "Create", raceid = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
          );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Which I'm trying to use with Actionlink

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add Person", "Create", "People", new { raceid = item.RaceId, id="1" })
```

I basically want the url to look like "/people/create/5/1"

But the HTML generated looks like

```
<a href="/races/Create?Length=6" id="1" raceid="5">Add Person</a>
```

It should say `<a href="/people/Create/5/1">Add Person</a>`

The page I'm on is http://localhost:57355/races

If I do just  `@Html.ActionLink("Add Person", "Create", "People")` then it works but I get no parameters.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493068.aspx) of the method.  Add a null at the end:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add Person", "Create", "People", new { raceid = item.RaceId, id="1" }, null)
```

Here is the overload:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    RouteValueDictionary routeValues,
    IDictionary<string, Object> htmlAttributes
)
```

or is it this one:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```